# How to create column with percentage differences between numbers in the same column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL and I thought a good way to apply what I know would be to attempt a little project I found. I've been able to find the yearly revenue but the prompt asks for percentage change from previous year. I can't seem to figure out how to add a column with this percent change.

I've tried using ISNULL, DATEDIFF, and LAG but I don't think I'm using it correctly.

Here's the code that creates the table:

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y', InvoiceDate) AS integer) AS YearOfSale, SUM(Total) AS TotalRev
FROM invoices
GROUP BY 1;
```

And the code I've tried to use to create the new column:

```
WITH yearlySales AS (
    SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y', InvoiceDate) AS integer) AS YearOfSale, SUM(Total) AS TotalRev
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT X.*, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(year, X.PREVDATE, X.YearOfSales),0) AS YearDiff
FROM (SELECT y.*, LAG(y.YearlySales) OVER( ORDER BY YEARLYSALES) AS PREVDATE  FROM yearlySales y )X;
```

I would expect the column to look like the following:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+
| YearOfSale | TotalRev | PercentDiff |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2009       | 449.46   | 7.12        |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2010       | 481.45   | -2.46       |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2011       | 469.58   | 1.69        |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2012       | 477.53   | -5.64       |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2013       | 450.58   | null        |
+------------+----------+-------------+
```

My code won't even compile on DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y', InvoiceDate) AS integer) AS YearOfSale,
       SUM(Total) AS TotalRev,
       SUM(TOTAL) / LAG(SUM(TOTAL)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(InvoiceDate)) - 1
FROM invoices
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very close, just had to subtract one from the produced values!